# Calculating moving average

Tags: r, moving-average

I'm trying to use R to calculate the moving average over a series of values in a matrix. There doesn't seem to be a [built-in function](http://www.statmethods.net/management/functions.html) in R that will allow me to calculate moving averages. Do any packages provide one? Or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

- Rolling Means/Maximums/Medians in the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) package (rollmean)
- MovingAverages in [TTR](http://cran.r-project.org/package=TTR)
- ma in [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast)

Comment: What is the moving average in R not containing future values of given timestamp? I checked `forecast::ma` and it contains all neighbourhood, not right.

Comment: Try the `stats::filter` function instead. There you can set `sides = 1`for only past values. E.g. `stats::filter(x, rep(1,5), sides = 1)/5` for the mean over 5 values.

Comment: I would add `frollmean` function in data.table.

Answer (score 256):

Or you can simply calculate it using filter, here's the function I use:

```
ma <- function(x, n = 5){filter(x, rep(1 / n, n), sides = 2)}
```

If you use `dplyr`, be careful to specify `stats::filter` in the function above.

Comment: I should point out that "sides=2" may be an important option in many people's use cases that they don't want to overlook. If you want only trailing information in your moving average, you should use sides=1.

Comment: Some years later but dplyr now has a filter function, if you have this package loaded use `stats::filter`

Comment: `sides = 2` is equivalent to align="center" for the zoo::rollmean or RcppRoll::roll_mean. `sides = 1` is equivalent to "right" alignment. I don't see a way to do "left" alignment or calculate with "partial" data (2 or more values)?

Comment: `stats::filter` gives a time series object. Pass the result to `as.vector` to get a vector.

Comment: This may be useful to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61777773/3348414

Answer (score 38):

Using `cumsum` should be sufficient and efficient. Assuming you have a vector *x* and you want a running sum of *n* numbers

```
cx <- c(0,cumsum(x))
rsum <- (cx[(n+1):length(cx)] - cx[1:(length(cx) - n)]) / n
```

As pointed out in the comments by @mzuther, this assumes that there are no NAs in the data. to deal with those would require dividing each window by the number of non-NA values. Here's one way of doing that, incorporating the comment from @Ricardo Cruz:

```
cx <- c(0, cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))
cn <- c(0, cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1)))
rx <- cx[(n+1):length(cx)] - cx[1:(length(cx) - n)]
rn <- cn[(n+1):length(cx)] - cn[1:(length(cx) - n)]
rsum <- rx / rn
```

This still has the issue that if all the values in the window are NAs then there will be a division by zero error.

Comment: One downside to this solution is that it can't handle missings: `cumsum(c(1:3,NA,1:3))`

Comment: @Ricardo Cruz: it might be better to remove the NAs and adjust the vector length accordingly. Think of a vector with a lot of NAs -- zeros will pull the average toward zero, while removing the NAs will leave the average as it is. It all depends on your data and the question you want to answer, of course. :)

Comment: @mzuther, I updated the answer following your comments. Thanks for the input. I think the correct way of dealing with missing data is not extending the window (by removing the NA values), but by averaging each window by the correct denominator.

Comment: rn <- cn[(n+1):length(cx)] - cx[1:(length(cx) - n)] should actually be rn <- cn[(n+1):length(cx)] - cn[1:(length(cx) - n)]

Comment: You also have to handle Inf values, no?

Comment: Actually, I think Inf are naturally handled correctly. Averaging over data that holds an Inf will result in an Inf. I'm not sure what happens (or should happen) if there are both Inf and -Inf, though

Answer (score 32):

In **data.table 1.12.0** new `frollmean` function has been added to compute fast and exact rolling mean carefully handling `NA`, `NaN` and `+Inf`, `-Inf` values.

As there is no reproducible example in the question there is not much more to address here.

You can find more info about `?frollmean` in manual, also available online at [`?frollmean`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/froll.html).

Examples from manual below:

```r
library(data.table)
d = as.data.table(list(1:6/2, 3:8/4))

# rollmean of single vector and single window
frollmean(d[, V1], 3)

# multiple columns at once
frollmean(d, 3)

# multiple windows at once
frollmean(d[, .(V1)], c(3, 4))

# multiple columns and multiple windows at once
frollmean(d, c(3, 4))

## three above are embarrassingly parallel using openmp
```

Answer (score 13):

The `caTools` package has very fast rolling mean/min/max/sd and few other functions. I've only worked with `runmean` and `runsd` and they are the fastest of any of the other packages mentioned to date.

Comment: This is awesome! It is the only function that does this in a nice, simple way. And it's 2018 now...

Answer (score 12):

Here is example code showing how to compute a *centered moving average* and a *trailing moving average* using the `rollmean` function from the [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

some_data = tibble(day = 1:10)
# cma = centered moving average
# tma = trailing moving average
some_data = some_data %>%
    mutate(cma = rollmean(day, k = 3, fill = NA)) %>%
    mutate(tma = rollmean(day, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right"))
some_data
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>      day   cma   tma
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1    NA    NA
#>  2     2     2    NA
#>  3     3     3     2
#>  4     4     4     3
#>  5     5     5     4
#>  6     6     6     5
#>  7     7     7     6
#>  8     8     8     7
#>  9     9     9     8
#> 10    10    NA     9
```

Comment: You can use one mutate call for multiple new columns by separating each new column with a comma.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `RcppRoll` for very quick moving averages written in C++. Just call the `roll_mean` function. Docs can be found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/RcppRoll.pdf).

Otherwise, this (slower) for loop should do the trick:

```
ma <- function(arr, n=15){
  res = arr
  for(i in n:length(arr)){
    res[i] = mean(arr[(i-n):i])
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me in details, how does this algorithm work?
Because I cannot understand the idea

Comment: First he initializes a vector of the same length with `res = arr`. Then there is a loop that iterates starting at `n` or, the 15th element, to the end of the array. that means the very first subset he takes the mean of is `arr[1:15]` which fills spot `res[15]`. Now, I prefer setting`res = rep(NA, length(arr))` instead of `res = arr` so each element of `res[1:14]` equals NA rather than a number, where we couldn't take a full average of 15 elements.

Comment: I think it should be `arr[(i-n+1):i]`

Answer (score 7):

In fact `RcppRoll` is very good.

The code posted by [cantdutchthis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600821/cantdutchthis) must be corrected in the fourth line to the window be fixed:

```
ma <- function(arr, n=15){
  res = arr
  for(i in n:length(arr)){
    res[i] = mean(arr[(i-n+1):i])
  }
  res
}
```

Another way, which handles missings, is given [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Calculating_a_moving_average/).

A third way, improving [cantdutchthis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600821/cantdutchthis) code to calculate partial averages or not, follows:

```
  ma <- function(x, n=2,parcial=TRUE){
  res = x #set the first values

  if (parcial==TRUE){
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      t<-max(i-n+1,1)
      res[i] = mean(x[t:i])
    }
    res

  }else{
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      t<-max(i-n+1,1)
      res[i] = mean(x[t:i])
    }
    res[-c(seq(1,n-1,1))] #remove the n-1 first,i.e., res[c(-3,-4,...)]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may calculate the moving average of a vector `x` with a window width of `k` by:

```
apply(embed(x, k), 1, mean)
```

Comment: An extension of this to data.frames is: `apply(df,rc,FUN=function(x) apply(embed(x, k),1,mean))` . `rc` can be one or two, for rows or columns, respectively.

Comment: this is not moving average

Answer (score 5):

In order to complement the answer of  [cantdutchthis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600821/cantdutchthis) and [Rodrigo Remedio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5490241/rodrigo-remedio);

```
moving_fun <- function(x, w, FUN, ...) {
  # x: a double vector
  # w: the length of the window, i.e., the section of the vector selected to apply FUN
  # FUN: a function that takes a vector and return a summarize value, e.g., mean, sum, etc.
  # Given a double type vector apply a FUN over a moving window from left to the right, 
  #    when a window boundary is not a legal section, i.e. lower_bound and i (upper bound) 
  #    are not contained in the length of the vector, return a NA_real_
  if (w < 1) {
    stop("The length of the window 'w' must be greater than 0")
  }
  output <- x
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
     # plus 1 because the index is inclusive with the upper_bound 'i'
    lower_bound <- i - w + 1
    if (lower_bound < 1) {
      output[i] <- NA_real_
    } else {
      output[i] <- FUN(x[lower_bound:i, ...])
    }
  }
  output
}

# example
v <- seq(1:10)

# compute a MA(2)
moving_fun(v, 2, mean)

# compute moving sum of two periods
moving_fun(v, 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

The slider package can be used for this. It has an interface that has been specifically designed to feel similar to purrr. It accepts any arbitrary function, and can return any type of output. Data frames are even iterated over row wise. The pkgdown site is [here](https://davisvaughan.github.io/slider/).

```r
library(slider)

x <- 1:3

# Mean of the current value + 1 value before it
# returned as a double vector
slide_dbl(x, ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .before = 1)
#> [1] 1.0 1.5 2.5


df <- data.frame(x = x, y = x)

# Slide row wise over data frames
slide(df, ~.x, .before = 1)
#> [[1]]
#>   x y
#> 1 1 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   x y
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   x y
#> 1 2 2
#> 2 3 3
```

The overhead of both slider and data.table's `frollapply()` should be pretty low (much faster than zoo). `frollapply()` looks to be a little faster for this simple example here, but note that it only takes numeric input, and the output must be a scalar numeric value. slider functions are completely generic, and you can return any data type.

```r
library(slider)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

x <- 1:50000 + 0L

bench::mark(
  slider = slide_int(x, function(x) 1L, .before = 5, .complete = TRUE),
  zoo = rollapplyr(x, FUN = function(x) 1L, width = 6, fill = NA),
  datatable = frollapply(x, n = 6, FUN = function(x) 1L),
  iterations = 200
)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 slider      19.82ms   26.4ms     38.4    829.8KB     19.0
#> 2 zoo        177.92ms  211.1ms      4.71    17.9MB     24.8
#> 3 datatable    7.78ms   10.9ms     87.9    807.1KB     38.7
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: took great joy in adding the `side` parameter, for a moving average (or sum, or ...) of e.g. the past 7 days of a `Date` vector.

---

For people just wanting to calculate this themselves, it's nothing more than:

```
# x = vector with numeric data
# w = window length
y <- numeric(length = length(x))

for (i in seq_len(length(x))) {
  ind <- c((i - floor(w / 2)):(i + floor(w / 2)))
  ind <- ind[ind %in% seq_len(length(x))]
  y[i] <- mean(x[ind])
}

y
```

But it gets fun to make it independent of `mean()`, so you can calculate any 'moving' function!

```
# our working horse:
moving_fn <- function(x, w, fun, ...) {
  # x = vector with numeric data
  # w = window length
  # fun = function to apply
  # side = side to take, (c)entre, (l)eft or (r)ight
  # ... = parameters passed on to 'fun'
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  for (i in seq_len(length(x))) {
    if (side %in% c("c", "centre", "center")) {
      ind <- c((i - floor(w / 2)):(i + floor(w / 2)))
    } else if (side %in% c("l", "left")) {
      ind <- c((i - floor(w) + 1):i)
    } else if (side %in% c("r", "right")) {
      ind <- c(i:(i + floor(w) - 1))
    } else {
      stop("'side' must be one of 'centre', 'left', 'right'", call. = FALSE)
    }
    ind <- ind[ind %in% seq_len(length(x))]
    y[i] <- fun(x[ind], ...)
  }
  y
}

# and now any variation you can think of!
moving_average <- function(x, w = 5, side = "centre", na.rm = FALSE) {
  moving_fn(x = x, w = w, fun = mean, side = side, na.rm = na.rm)
}

moving_sum <- function(x, w = 5, side = "centre", na.rm = FALSE) {
  moving_fn(x = x, w = w, fun = sum, side = side, na.rm = na.rm)
}

moving_maximum <- function(x, w = 5, side = "centre", na.rm = FALSE) {
  moving_fn(x = x, w = w, fun = max, side = side, na.rm = na.rm)
}

moving_median <- function(x, w = 5, side = "centre", na.rm = FALSE) {
  moving_fn(x = x, w = w, fun = median, side = side, na.rm = na.rm)
}

moving_Q1 <- function(x, w = 5, side = "centre", na.rm = FALSE) {
  moving_fn(x = x, w = w, fun = quantile, side = side, na.rm = na.rm, 0.25)
}

moving_Q3 <- function(x, w = 5, side = "centre", na.rm = FALSE) {
  moving_fn(x = x, w = w, fun = quantile, side = side, na.rm = na.rm, 0.75)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though a bit slow but you can also use zoo::rollapply to perform calculations on matrices.

```
reqd_ma <- rollapply(x, FUN = mean, width = n)
```

where x is the data set, FUN = mean is the function; you can also change it to min, max, sd etc and width is the rolling window.

Comment: It is not slow;. Comparing it to base R, it is *much* faster.  `set.seed(123); x <- rnorm(1000); system.time(apply(embed(x, 5), 1, mean)); 
library(zoo); system.time(rollapply(x, 5, mean))`  On my machine it is so fast that it returns a time of 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [`runner`](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) package for moving functions. In this case `mean_run` function. Problem with `cummean` is that it doesn't handle `NA` values, but `mean_run` does. `runner` package also supports irregular time series and windows can depend on date:

```r
library(runner)
set.seed(11)
x1 <- rnorm(15)
x2 <- sample(c(rep(NA,5), rnorm(15)), 15, replace = TRUE)
date <- Sys.Date() + cumsum(sample(1:3, 15, replace = TRUE))

mean_run(x1)
#>  [1] -0.5910311 -0.2822184 -0.6936633 -0.8609108 -0.4530308 -0.5332176
#>  [7] -0.2679571 -0.1563477 -0.1440561 -0.2300625 -0.2844599 -0.2897842
#> [13] -0.3858234 -0.3765192 -0.4280809

mean_run(x2, na_rm = TRUE)
#>  [1] -0.18760011 -0.09022066 -0.06543317  0.03906450 -0.12188853 -0.13873536
#>  [7] -0.13873536 -0.14571604 -0.12596067 -0.11116961 -0.09881996 -0.08871569
#> [13] -0.05194292 -0.04699909 -0.05704202

mean_run(x2, na_rm = FALSE )
#>  [1] -0.18760011 -0.09022066 -0.06543317  0.03906450 -0.12188853 -0.13873536
#>  [7]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
#> [13]          NA          NA          NA

mean_run(x2, na_rm = TRUE, k = 4)
#>  [1] -0.18760011 -0.09022066 -0.06543317  0.03906450 -0.10546063 -0.16299272
#>  [7] -0.21203756 -0.39209010 -0.13274756 -0.05603811 -0.03894684  0.01103493
#> [13]  0.09609256  0.09738460  0.04740283

mean_run(x2, na_rm = TRUE, k = 4, idx = date)
#> [1] -0.187600111 -0.090220655 -0.004349696  0.168349653 -0.206571573 -0.494335093
#> [7] -0.222969541 -0.187600111 -0.087636571  0.009742884  0.009742884  0.012326968
#> [13]  0.182442234  0.125737145  0.059094786
```

One can also specify other options like `lag`, and roll only `at` specific indexes. More in [package](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/index.html) and [function](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/reference/mean_run.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function with `filter` demonstrating one way to take care of beginning and ending NAs with padding, and computing a weighted average (supported by `filter`) using custom weights:

```
wma <- function(x) { 
  wts <- c(seq(0.5, 4, 0.5), seq(3.5, 0.5, -0.5))
  nside <- (length(wts)-1)/2
  # pad x with begin and end values for filter to avoid NAs
  xp <- c(rep(first(x), nside), x, rep(last(x), nside)) 
  z <- stats::filter(xp, wts/sum(wts), sides = 2) %>% as.vector 
  z[(nside+1):(nside+length(x))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector_avg <- function(x){
  sum_x = 0
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(!is.na(x[i]))
      sum_x = sum_x + x[i]
  }
  return(sum_x/length(x))
}
```

Comment: Please add a description for further detail.

Comment: Please relate your answer to the question and include some output which shows the question has been answered. See [answer] for guidance on making a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use aggregate along with a vector created by rep().  This has the advantage of using cbind() to aggregate more than 1 column in your dataframe at time.  Below is an example of a moving average of 60 for a vector (v) of length 1000:

```
v=1:1000*0.002+rnorm(1000)
mrng=rep(1:round(length(v)/60+0.5), length.out=length(v), each=60)
aggregate(v~mrng, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
```

Note the first argument in rep is to simply get enough unique values for the moving range, based on the length of the vector and the amount to be averaged; the second argument keeps the length equal to the vector length, and the last repeats the values of the first argument the same number of times as the averaging period.

In aggregate you could use several functions (median, max, min) - mean shown for example.  Again, could could use a formula with cbind to do this on more than one (or all) columns in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful function if you want the two ends of series not to be NA but to be recursively calculated moving averages:

```
smoothing = function(x, k=1) {
  sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    i.min = max(i-k, 1)
    i.max = min(i+k, length(x))
    mean(x[i.min:i.max], na.rm=TRUE)
  })
}
```

Example:

```
x = 1:10/2
```

[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0

```
smoothing(x, 2)
```

[1] 1.00 1.25 1.50 2.00 2.50 3.00 3.50 4.00 4.25 4.50