# moving averages in R

Tags: r, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating moving average in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r)

Is there a function to compute leading, lagging, central moving averages in R similar to [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/finance/movavg.html)? I was trying to use the [filter function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/filter.html) but can't get my head around it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r

Answer (score 0):

I've used the SMA function in the [TTR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/index.html).