# Apply a function to a specified range; Rate of Change

Tags: r, apply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating moving average in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r)

I have written a rate of change function in R, defined as:

```
rateChange <- function(x) ((last(x)-first(x))/first(x))*100
```

It works wonderfully on various date ranges, such as the rate of change for 5 days, 10 days, 200 days, etc. However, I now have need to apply this function between every day. For example, to identify the rate of change for 5 days one would require the past 6 data observations.

Here is an example in Excel, and for clarity, I am trying to reproduce the "Rate of Change" column:

[image: data]

Thank you!

Comment: I voted to close but I now believe that decision was incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using `TTR::ROC`:

```
library(TTR)
roc <- c(18.89, 18.93, 18.55, 18.77, 18.87, 18.91)
ROC(roc, type="discrete")*100
# [1]         NA  0.2117522 -2.0073957  1.1859838  0.5327651  0.2119767
```

Comment: @user1499626 - You mean "this is _a_ solution".  There is almost always more than one way to do things in R.

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- rnorm(5)
x
#[1] -0.48504744 -1.71843913  0.03890147 -2.11410329 -1.59765182
100*(tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1))/head(x, -1)
#[1]   254.28269  -102.26377 -5534.50754  -24.42887
```

If you need it to be the same length as the input vector you could just add an NA onto the end like this

```
c(100*(tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1))/head(x, -1), NA)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is close but the math (outcome) isn't exactly the same:

```
 roc <- c(18.89, 18.93, 18.55, 18.77, 18.87, 18.91)
 sapply(seq_along(roc)[-1], function(i) 100*(roc[i] - roc[i-1])/roc[i-1])
```