# Moving average with varying time window in R

Tags: r

I want to compute a moving average over a certain time window without generating NAs at the beginning of the time series. For instance, if I set the time window to 3, the 2 first observations will have NAs. What I want is to have a time window of 1 for the first observation, 2 for the second observation, and then 3 for all the remaining observations.

My current code:

```
#example data
x <- c(3,9,2,8,4,6,5,8)
#moving average with time window of length 3
(ma3 <- filter(x,rep(1/3,3),sides=1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rep(1/3, 3)`?

Comment: Indeed. I edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a way other than brute-force:

Using `rollapply` from package `zoo` instead of `filter`:

```
c(x[1], mean(x[1:2]), rollapply(x, width=3, FUN=mean))
```

Comment: Or staying with base R you could do: `ma3 <- c(x[1], mean(x[1:2]),filter(x,rep(1/3,3),sides=1)[3:length(x)])`

Answer (score 3):

Let me jump on the `rollapply` train, too:

```
> rollapply(c(NA, NA, x), width=3, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
[1] 3.000000 6.000000 4.666667 6.333333 4.666667 6.000000 5.000000 6.333333
```

Prepending two = 3-1 `NA` values and using `na.rm=T` has the effect of extending the time series but ignoring the new values for calculating the mean. A slightly more difficult but otherwise equivalent syntax

```
> rollapply(c(NA, NA, x), width=3, FUN=function(v) mean(v, na.rm=T))
```

Thanks to Matthew for pointing this out.

Comment: And it is still present!  Look at what `rollapply` does with `...`

Answer (score 2):

@thelatemail has done a great job, but he had an error in the code (`test[]` should be replaced with `x[]` inside the function) and more importantly he had to do the same thing for the end of the vector (if you want side=2). Also the window size should be twice+1 of the ith element in the vector (and n-ith element at the end).
so, here is the final version:

```
movavg.grow = function(x,window) {
  startma = sapply(1:(floor(window/2)),function(y) mean(x[1:((y-1)*2+1)]))
  endma = sapply(1:(floor(window/2)),function(y) mean(x[(length(x)-((y-1)*2)):length(x)]))
  endma = rev(endma)
  c(startma,
    filter(x,rep(1/window,window))[(floor(window/2):(length(x)- floor(window)/2)+1)],
    endma)
}
```

As for a test, what you want must return `1:10` for `x=1:10`

```
> x=1:10
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> movavg.grow(x,5)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> movavg.grow(x,3)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Feature you are asking is called 'partial' window and AFAIK it is already available in zoo package.

There is also new **fast rolling mean** function in **data.table** to be released in **1.12.0**.
Unfortunately it does not support partial window, but you can achieve desired behavior using 'adaptive' feature of that function in the following way:

```r
x = c(3,9,2,8,4,6,5,8)
window = 3

library(data.table)
n = c(seq.int(window), rep(window, length(x)-window))
frollmean(x, n, adaptive=TRUE)
#[1] 3.000000 6.000000 4.666667 6.333333 4.666667 6.000000 5.000000 6.333333
```

You can find manual entry for new function online at [`?froll`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/froll.html).

Answer (score 1):

Add zero's to the beginning and ending of your sequence with the size of the moving average. This will prevent NAs.

Comment: ...but yield incorrect results, e.g. only 1/3 of the first observation will be reported.

Comment: You should see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r

Comment: Thanks for the link, but what exactly I am supposed to see?

Comment: There are some functions other than filter that might do what you want; not sure though....

Answer (score 1):

A custom function in base R to get you there:

```
movavg.grow <- function(x,window,sides) {
 startma <- sapply(1:(window-1),function(y) mean(x[1:y]))
 c(startma,filter(x,rep(1/window,window),sides=sides)[window:length(x)])
}
```

Test it:

```
> test <- c(3,9,2,8,4,6,5,8)
> movavg.grow(x=test,window=3,sides=1)
[1] 3.000000 6.000000 4.666667 6.333333 4.666667 6.000000 5.000000 6.333333
```