# Computing rolling mean in data.table with adaptive window lengths

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking to compute a moving average by group in a data.table with an adaptive window so that there are no NAs at the beginning of the time series. I know how to do this with frollmean and setting adaptive = TRUE (see for instance jangorecki's response in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926572/moving-average-with-varying-time-window-in-r) thread). I can get the same code to work when all groups in my data.table are of the same length but run into errors when the groups are of different size.

For example, if my data is

```
tmp = data.table(Gp = c(rep('A',6),rep('B',4)), Val = c(1,3,4,6,2,2,8,5,7,10))
```

and I am doing a moving average of length 3, then the desired response is

```
> desired_output
    Gp  Val
 1:  A 1.00
 2:  A 2.00
 3:  A 2.67
 4:  A 4.33
 5:  A 4.00
 6:  A 3.33
 7:  B 8.00
 8:  B 6.50
 9:  B 6.67
10:  B 7.33
```

I tried the following:

```
mov_window_len = vector("list",2)
mov_window_len[[1]] = c(1,2,rep(3,4))
mov_window_len[[2]] = c(1,2,rep(3,2))
tmp[,lapply(.SD, frollmean, n = mov_window_len, align = "right", adaptive = TRUE), by = Gp]
```

but I get an error saying `length of integer vector(s) provided as list to 'n' argument must be equal to number of observations provided in 'x'`

Any help in resolving this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the group index `.GRP` to subset `mov_window_len`. This will give you the right lengths for each group. You only want to take `frollmean` of `Val`, so no need for `lapply`.

```
tmp[, frollmean(Val, n = mov_window_len[.GRP], align = "right", adaptive = TRUE), by = Gp]

#     Gp       V1
#  1:  A 1.000000
#  2:  A 2.000000
#  3:  A 2.666667
#  4:  A 4.333333
#  5:  A 4.000000
#  6:  A 3.333333
#  7:  B 8.000000
#  8:  B 6.500000
#  9:  B 6.666667
# 10:  B 7.333333
```

Alternatively window length can be added to input data.table (`Len` field below), as it corresponds to each row.

```r
tmp[Gp=="A", Len:=mov_window_len[[1]]
    ][Gp=="B", Len:=mov_window_len[[2]]
     ][, .(Val, Len, RollVal=frollmean(Val, Len, adaptive=TRUE)), by=Gp]
#    Gp Val Len  RollVal
# 1:  A   1   1 1.000000
# 2:  A   3   2 2.000000
# 3:  A   4   3 2.666667
# 4:  A   6   3 4.333333
# 5:  A   2   3 4.000000
# 6:  A   2   3 3.333333
# 7:  B   8   1 8.000000
# 8:  B   5   2 6.500000
# 9:  B   7   3 6.666667
#10:  B  10   3 7.333333
```

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know about .GRP. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: `align="right"` is the default. Thanks for answer, AFAIK it is the first not provided by me answer that uses adaptive=T :)

Comment: added alternative way which might be seen a little bit cleaner as integrates window len into data