# Improving efficiency in R program

Tags: r

I am new to the R language and as you will most likely notice I have some experience in C. I am working on making my program run faster and thus be more efficient.

The code below is just calculating a simple moving average from the data set:

```
library(quantmod)
StockData1 <- getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign=FALSE, from="1984-01-01")
```

As far as I could find there is no quick pre-made function that will just do it for me so I made my own.

```
moving_avg <- function(StockData, MA, CurrentDay){

  #MA = Days long the MA is
  #CurrentDay = What day we are currently on

  MAValue <- NULL
  n <- 0
  total <- 0
  start <- CurrentDay - MA
  repeat {
    total <- total + StockData[[start, 4]]
    start <- start + 1
    n <- n + 1
    if(n == MA){
      break
    }
  }
  MAValue <- total/MA
  return(MAValue)
}
```

I tested it using microbenchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(print(moving_avg(StockData1, 256, 300)))
```

My results were around 1000 microseconds which I find pretty slow for such a simple function.

Comment: There are many quick, pre-made functions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/743812/903061

Comment: Existing code for moving averages: [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Calculating_a_moving_average), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/743846/3005513).

Comment: If you are familiar with C then maybe try [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)?

Comment: You know, you didn't need to change your user name.  +1 for making your code simple and  reproducible; see the first comment for answers.

Comment: all your function does for me is `sum(StockData1[(300 - 256):(300 - 1), 4]) / 256` not a moving average