# How to calculated the max average hourly value for a day without using loop in R

Tags: r

I have minute data for a day, and I want to find the max hourly average value. It doesn't have to be on the hour (`5:07`~`6:07` works too, which means I have to calculate average value for `00:00`~`01:00`, `00:01`~`01:01`, `00:02`~`01:02`......). Anything I can use other than loop?

Comment: What does your data look like? Sounds like a case for `?filter`, that is, calculate a moving window average, then find the `?max`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r

Comment: use `dput()` on your data, then copy the output from the R console into your question, if you want more help.

Comment: It's a non-overlapping rolling mean, right? In that case, the problem is a bit simpler.

Comment: @rbatt No I need the overlapping rolling mean>< the link in the first comment contains several function that works for me. I should've attached a pic or a table to show my data (but I don't know how_(:з」∠)_  ).

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is a vector of times, as a character string, and `y` is the data you want to average, you can do something like this:

```
x <- c("0:00", "0:01", "12:00", "12:05", "18:04", "18:05", "18:06", "18:07", "0:00", "0:01")
x <- gsub(":[0-9]{2,}", "", x ,perl=T)

y <- 1:length(x)

hourly.average <- aggregate(list(y=y), by=list(x=x), mean)

max.hourly.average <- max(hourly.average[,"y"])
```

So you get

```
> hourly.average
   x   y
1  0 5.5
2 12 3.5
3 18 6.5
```

And for the precise answer to your question,

```
> max.hourly.average
[1] 6.5
```