# Transforming data frame processing slowly - R

Tags: r, performance, optimization

Good morning,

I'm running a block of code and its taking a bit too long. The goal is to make a "moving average" of the last X number of days. In this case, the previous 2, 3, 4, and 5 days of scores. It needs to be from the last date `Date`, for a unique id `EID`. Here it the data:

```
df:
     EID            Date        Score
     1111         5/25/2015        10
     1111         5/29/2015         6
     1111         6/17/2015         9
    12345         5/27/2015        10
    12345          1/1/2015         8
    12345          1/7/2015         9
    12345          1/9/2015        10
    12345         1/10/2015         7
    19611         1/13/2015         8
    19611         1/21/2015        10
    19611         1/23/2015         9
    19611         1/24/2015        10
    19611         1/30/2015         5
    19611          2/5/2015         6
    19611         2/11/2015        10
    19611         2/12/2015         7
    19611         2/14/2015        10
    19611         2/15/2015         6
    19611         2/18/2015        10
    19611         2/19/2015        10
```

This is what I'm currently running on 500,000+ rows across 6 data frames

```
uniqueID <- unique(df$EID)
rowNr    <- lapply(uniqueID,function(uniqueID){which(df$EID==uniqueID)})
lastDate <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){df$Date[rev(n)[1]]})
Avg      <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(df$Score[n])})
prev2    <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(df$Score[head(tail(c(NA,n),3),2)])})
prev3    <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(df$Score[head(tail(c(NA,n),4),3)])})
prev4    <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(df$Score[head(tail(c(NA,n),5),4)])})
prev5    <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(df$Score[head(tail(c(NA,n),6),5)])})

Scores <- data.frame(EID       = uniqueID,                       
                     avg_score = unlist(Avg),                       
                     score2    = unlist(prev2),                       
                     score3    = unlist(prev3),                       
                     score4    = unlist(prev4),                       
                     score5    = unlist(prev5))
```

Here are the results

```
View(Scores)
EID     avg_score   score2  score3  score4  score5
1111    8.33        7.50    8.33    NA      NA
12345   8.80        8.50    8.67    8.50    8.80
19611   8.42        10.00   8.67    9.00    8.60
```

Any ideas to make this run faster? Im currently running this on 6 data frames and it takes 10-15 minutes for each one to process. 
How can this be optimized to run faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `data.table` package. It plays nicer with large data than base R.

Comment: Possible dupe:  [Calculating moving average in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/743812/903061)? It's not performance-focused, but I would bet most of the answers are more performant than this one, and a couple of them mention performance (see the `caTools` and `RcppRoll` answers).

Comment: ...though it could definitely do with a `data.table` answer.

Comment: Can't you put `lastDate`, `Avg`, `prev2`, `prev3`, `prev4`, `prev5` in a single `lapply`? They all use `rowNr` for their iterative value and look independent of each other.

Comment: Looking at the first group `"1111"`, the `"score2"` column has `8.0`. That is the average of `(10+6)/2`. That's the first two days, not the last two. Is that the desired output? Because for the third group you are selecting 6 and 10. That doesn't make sense. How could both of those be the correct moving average for score2?

Comment: Pierre Lafortune, good catch. It should be the last 2. I need to figure out whats wrong and fix. Ultimately, the result should be from the last day of observations for a given EID.

Comment: I'm still new so my apologies.

Comment: This line `aggregate(df$Score,df["EID"],function(x) {y<-rev(x[-length(x)]);length(y)<-5;c(mean(x),cumsum(y)[-1]/2:5)})` reproduces your final result.

Comment: @nicola, Thank you for the help!!! This is brilliant. I dont understand it, but it does produce the original answers I posted. However, it was brought to my attention that I was calculating those differently than I described (I've updated my solution). I need to include the last score when calculating the mean over the previous 2,3,4,5 day. Additionally, sometimes, I need to change the dates from being sequential (2,3,4,5) to dates like: 5, 10, 15, 20. Any thoughts?

Comment: The rows for `EID==12345` are not in date order. Are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
n      <- c(2,3,4,5)
result <- setDT(df)[,c(mean(Score),lapply(n,function(i){if(.N < i) as.numeric(NA) else mean(tail(Score,i))})),by=EID]
setnames(result,c("EID","avg_score",paste0("score",n)))
result
#      EID avg_score score2   score3 score4 score5
# 1:  1111  8.333333    7.5 8.333333     NA     NA
# 2: 12345  8.800000    8.5 8.666667    8.5    8.8
# 3: 19611  8.416667   10.0 8.666667    9.0    8.6
```

This reproduces your result, but as pointed out in the comment your rows are not in date order for all the `EID`s. If that is important, use this:

```
setDT(df)[,Date:=as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
setkey(df,EID,Date)     # ensures that Dates are ascending within EID
n      <- c(2,3,4,5)
result <- df[,c(mean(Score),lapply(n,function(i){if(.N < i) as.numeric(NA) else mean(tail(Score,i))})),by=EID]
setnames(result,c("EID","avg_score",paste0("score",n)))
result
#      EID avg_score score2   score3 score4 score5
# 1:  1111  8.333333    7.5 8.333333     NA     NA
# 2: 12345  8.800000    8.5 9.000000      9    8.8
# 3: 19611  8.416667   10.0 8.666667      9    8.6
```

If you need rollback averages other than (2,3,4,5), change the definition of `n`.