# are there any functions in R like pd.ewma?

Tags: python, r, missing-data, exponential, moving-average

I tried TTR::EMA and TTR::WMA or other MA functions in TTR packages and I also tried qcc::ewma and qcc::ewmaSmooth, but none of them can deal with data with NA.
I know Python pandas package has function pd.ewma.
I may not know R well....can anybody know such function in R?

for example, in python:

```
a=pd.Series([1,4, np.nan, np.nan,1])
pd.ewma(a, span=2/0.01-1)

Out[137]: 
0    1.000000
1    2.507538
2    2.507538
3    2.507538
4    1.993177
dtype: float64
```

thanks

Comment: Anything here you might find useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r

Comment: Not an exact solution, but you could use the base function `filter` to apply any filter you want. You'd have to generate the weights manually, but that's not hard to do.

Comment: Just because a function "deals" with missing values, doesn't mean it's suitable for your application. Is it really okay to assume that there's no decay until the next non-missing value?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik i already know these packages but i think none of them have this capability...

Comment: @AlexeyShiklomanov i tried to do it manually but it was painful...that is why i am looking for a built-in function.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich actually i did use pandas.ewma to achieve my goal but i just want to know if R has similar functions or not...for sure my data has missing value btw...