# Exporting CSV files using R

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a problem exporting data tables to csv files for Excel. After loading data from excel files, I want to add new columns to the data and then export it as a new csv file for excel. When I do this a new column appears on the left with the numbers 1,2,3 ... and the other columns are actualy directed left.

Anyone already encountred this problem and figured out how to fix it ?

Comment: any code you can possible share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `write.table()` or `write.csv()` to export your data as a CSV. If so, then just use the `row.names = FALSE` argument to remove the first column which is the row names.

Comment: It works perfectly! thank you very much! Would you know how to implement a simple moving average for my data series?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r Also, if you feel that an answer has helped you solve your problem, you can check the green check mark to help let others know that this question has been solved.

Comment: thanks! I did it, it's just that I'm new on this forum ^^

Comment: No worries. Welcome!