# How to speed up/ improve rolling average function?

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, rollapply

My data is 988, 785 obs. of 3 variables. A smaller example of my data is below:

```
Names <- c("Jack", "Jill", "John")
RawAccelData <- data.frame(
  Sample = as.numeric(rep(1:60000, each = 3)),
  Acceleration = rnorm(6000),
  ID = rep((Names), each = 60000)
)
```

The sample rate of my equipment is 100 Hz. I wish to calculate a rolling average of `Acceleration` for each `ID` over a 1 to 10 second period. I perform this using the following:

```
require(dplyr)
require(zoo)

for (summaryFunction in c("mean")) {
  for ( i in seq(100, 1000, by = 100)) {
    tempColumn <- RawAccelData %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      transmute(rollapply(Acceleration,
                          width = i, 
                          FUN = summaryFunction, 
                          align = "right", 
                          fill = NA, 
                          na.rm = T))
    colnames(tempColumn)[2] <- paste("Rolling", summaryFunction, as.character(i), sep = ".")
    RawAccelData <- bind_cols(RawAccelData, tempColumn[2])
  }
}
```

However, I now need to calculate a rolling over a 1 to 10 minute period. I can do this by using the above code and substituting in the following line:

```
for ( i in seq(6000, 60000, by = 6000)) {
```

However, this takes hours to run through my dataset and results in RStudio on my Mac (details below) hanging! Is there a way I can a) tidy up the above code or b) use a different package/ method to enable a quicker result?

Thank you.

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] zoo_1.7-12  dplyr_0.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.1        assertthat_0.1  parallel_3.2.3  DBI_0.3.1      
 [7] tools_3.2.3     Rcpp_0.12.2     grid_3.2.3      lattice_0.20-33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have other summary functions in mind, but at least for the mean, you can speed up the `rollapply` function by using `filter` instead:
`transmute(stats::filter(Acceleration,rep(1/i,i),sides=1))`

(See other options here: [Calculating moving average in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r)) Using `system.time`, this sped me up from 117 secs to 4 secs!!

You can also do some `for` loops in parallel.
Instead of

```
for ( i in seq(6000, 60000, by = 6000)) {
```

try:

```
library(parallel)
for (summaryFunction in c("mean")) {
  rollCols = mclapply (seq(100, 1000, by = 100),function(i){
    tempColumn <- RawAccelData %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    transmute(stats::filter(Acceleration,rep(1/i,i),sides=1))
    colnames(tempColumn)[2] <- paste("Rolling", summaryFunction, as.character(i), sep = ".")
    return(tempColumn[2])
  })
}

RawAccelData = cbind(RawAccelData,do.call(cbind,rollCols))
```

This sped me up from 72 sec to 40 sec, but it depends on how many cores your computer has.

Comment: I am only interested in the mean, so thank you for the concise and useful answer.

Comment: In your answer, you please include the full code you used to run with the for loops in `Parallel`? My result is just printing in the console, rather than appending to `RawAccelData` like the code in my question.

Comment: You're right, I missed some details -- I just edited in the body of the code.

Comment: Perfect, appreciate it! This was much quicker than my initial code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is running slowly is that

1. the code in the question has defeated `rollapply`'s ability to detect that `mean` is being passed by assigning `mean` to a variable and passing that variable.  (In the case of `mean`, `rollapply` calls `rollmean` which contains optimized code for that case). Had the code in the question passed `mean` directly or had it used `rollmean` it would have been substantially faster.
2. `filter` does not remove NAs so for an apples to apples comparison one should *not* use `na.rm = TRUE` in `rollapply`.  If you do use it then it will also defeat the optimization.

For example, in this comparison `rollapply` runs more than twice as fast as `filter`:

```
library(zoo)
library(rbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
r <- rnorm(10000)
benchmark(filter = stats::filter(r, rep(1/100,100), sides = 1),
          rollapply = rollapplyr(r, 100, mean, fill = NA))[1:4]
```

giving:

```
       test replications elapsed relative
1    filter          100    3.75    2.119
2 rollapply          100    1.77    1.000
```

The speed may, of course, vary according to the `width`, data length and other aspects of the input since this is only one test.

Comment: I appreciate the context to why it is running slowly, this will assist me with creating code in the future. Thank you!