# How to calculate rolling mean for last N rows for every row

Tags: r

Hi I have a df and How to calculate rolling mean for previous N rows ,In my case it is 3

`df <- data.frame(X=c(24,NA,NA,45,NA,20,24,10,40,20,20), Y=c(10,NA,14,14,14,10,NA,10,14,14,14)`)

I tried to get o/p as below

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
df[, Rolling.Average := rollmeanr(X, 3, fill = NA), by = Y]
```

o/p:

```
X   Y  Rolling.Average
24  10  NA
NA  NA  NA
NA  14  NA
45  14  NA
NA  14  45
20  10  NA
24  NA  NA
10  10  20
40  14  NA
20  14  40
20  14  30
```

Error: k <= n is not TRUE
Any modifications in above code,please suggest
Thanks

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average)

Comment: Thanks AEBilgrau, the expected output is if the value in Y apears in last 3 rows then the average of X for that value in Roll.Ave  i.e-  for 14 in row id 3 we dont have same value in previous 3 rows, and for row-id 4 it appears in previous 3 rows and avg is NA,same for last row for 14 avg of for same value in previous 3 rows is 30

Comment: (My previous comment was gibberish, so here it is restated.)
What exactly is your expected output? How should `Y` equal to `NA` be interpreted with the `by` argument? And what do you expect the average should be with a right-aligned window when the first entries are `NA` for `Y`

Comment: Depending on what you want use `rollapplyr(X, 3, mean, partial = TRUE)` or `rollapplyr(X, 3, mean, partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)` or `rollapplyr(c(NA, NA, X), 3, mean)` or `rollapplyr(c(NA, NA, X), 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks Grothendieck, rollapplyr(X, 3, mean, partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE) is giving answer

Comment: Also, instead of calculates last 3 value of same value, can we modify it to previous N rows?

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown as you have less that 3 rows for the "NA" group -- which `data.table` seems to interpret as a group.

So, your data is expected to have at least three entries for each by-group. Then the code works (I have added a row below to your example below):

```
df <- data.frame(X=c(24,NA,NA,45,NA,20,24,10,40,20,20,20),
                 Y=c(10,NA,14,14,14,10,NA,10,14,14,14,NA))

library(data.table)
library(zoo)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, Rolling.Average := rollmeanr(X, k = 3, fill = NA), by = Y]
print(df)
#     X  Y Rolling.Average
# 1: 24 10              NA
# 2: NA NA              NA
# 3: NA 14              NA
# 4: 45 14              NA
# 5: NA 14              NA
# 6: 20 10              NA
# 7: 24 NA              NA
# 8: 10 10              18
# 9: 40 14              NA
#10: 20 14              NA
#11: 20 14              NA
#12: 20 NA              NA
```

Or, you can exclude the `NA`s of the by-clause by something like:

```
df[!is.na(Y), Rolling.Average := rollmeanr(X, k = 3, fill = NA), by = Y]
```

Which yields the same output. It does not match your expected output, but I do not really understand how one should arrive at that.