# Using dplyr's lead and lag with a range

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, lead

I am trying to create a function to calculate the mean of the last n rows in a `data.frame` for each row using tidyverse's syntax. So, the way I see it is using `lead` but dynamically with an `n` value. Something like `df %>% mutate(mean_5 = mean_last(value, 5)` where each row's value will be the mean of its own value and the last 4 values.

Manually, for a `n=3`case, it would be something like:

`df %>% mutate(av3 = (y + lead(y, 1) + lead(y, 2))/3)`

I've tried using `mean(lead(value, n=1:3))` but it doesn't work either.

## Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = c(10, 4, 8, 6, 5, 1))
df %>% mutate(av3 = (y + lead(y, 1) + lead(y, 2))/3)
```

Will return `df` with a new `av3` column with values `c(7.2, 6.0, 6.3, 4.0, NA, NA)`

I expect to get that output but automatically without having to type `n-1` times the `lead` function. Just something like `new_mean = mean(lead(value, 1:10))`

And last, it would be super nice if it lets you use the `group_by` function!

Comment: There you go @akrun :)

Comment: `lead` and `lag` weren't written with this in mind---I think any solution you come up with using them will be pretty hacky. Why not just use standard rolling functions like those mentioned in the [r-faq for moving averages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/743812/903061)?

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend the `data.table` implementation: `df %>% mutate(av3 = data.table::frollmean(y, n = 3, align = "left"))`.

Comment: *"And last, it would be super nice if it lets you use the group_by function!"* Anything you put inside `mutate` will use the `group_by` function. Mutate handles that, the functions inside `mutate` don't have to worry about it.