# How to calculate a moving average

Tags: r, ggplot2, moving-average

I came across this article in [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/03/19/world/coronavirus-flatten-the-curve-countries.html?fbclid=IwAR3AvCLvEA4ZfqZUbp43nCs801j6VRFFL1pvV-t6H504Amxq7A0Kvi9UPvI) today about coronavirus and I liked how the graphs were presented. I know the bar plots can is just using geom_col() in ggplot but I am more interested in the smoothing part. Just like this graph:

[image]

They said that "each red line is the seven-day moving average, which smooths out day-to-day anomalies..." How do you do that? I have a dataset that I plan to present it in a similar way.

Thanks!

Comment: See these https://uc-r.github.io/ts_moving_averages & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` also has a rolling mean function, `frollmean`, which can be used for this purpose:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# create some data
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(N = rescale(dnorm(seq(-10, 10, by=.1)) + 
        runif(201, -.1, .1), c(1, 800)))

# apply rolling mean over 10 data points
DT[, `:=`(rollN = frollmean(N, n = 10, align = "center"), idx = .I)]

ggplot(DT, aes(x=idx, y=N)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_line() + # original data
    geom_line(data=DT, aes(x=idx, y=rollN), colour = "red", size = 2) +  # rolling mean
    geom_histogram(aes(x=idx, weight = N/10), binwidth = 10, inherit.aes = FALSE, fill="red", alpha = .2) # histogram
#> Warning: Removed 9 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the insight and for the reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the 3 period moving average of the 3 points up to and including the current point.  The first two point are NA because there are not 3 points and the third is (1+2+3)/3=2 and the fourth is (2+3+4)/3=3 and so on.  Omit `fill = NA` if you don't want the NAs.  If you want centered moving averages remove the r at the end of rollmeanr.

```
library(zoo)
x <- 1:10 # test input
rollmeanr(x, 3, fill = NA)
## [1] NA NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

To take the averages of 3 or fewer points use rollapplyr with partial=TRUE.  Here the first point in the output is just 1 because the average of 1 is 1.  The second is (1+2)/2=1.5 and the remaining are as above.

```
rollapplyr(x, 3, mean, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0
```

See ?rollapply for more information.