# How to smooth a curve in R?

Tags: r, smoothing

[image]

```
location diffrence<-c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2)
Power<-c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1)
plot(location diffrence,Power)
```

The guy which has written the paper said he has smoothed the curve using a weighted moving average with weights vector w = (0.25,0.5,0.25) but he did not explained how he did this and with which function he achieved that.i am really confused

Comment: This is actual more of a question for CrossValidated than StackOverflow. But I would not advise you to smooth the curve, whether by linear or gaussian interpolation. These points have meaning, they are not just noise. If you want a smooth curve, fit a sigmoid curve or a logistic regression to your data and print this curve. They are smooth as hell and say something about your data. Just smoothing it out does not help anyone.

Comment: Please give us actual code/data. Here, `location diffrence` is not a legal name in R (without quoting/escaping), you are missing a close-paren on `Power`, and since their lengths are different, `plot` will error.

Comment: I provided an answer, but the more theoretical discussion of smoothing fits better on [stats.se] (as @MartinWettstein said), and how/when to use smoothed data also fits there and perhaps also on [datascience.se].

Comment: @r2evans Thank you but the code and the data do not give any further information it is just about plotting the power curve of a test .Sorry  Power is just a name of a vector not a built in function or something else

Comment: @MartinWettstein yes they do have meaning it is just that the professor who written the scientific paper says that he does not like these ugly points so he smoothed the curve with a weighted vector to get nicer shape

Comment: @ sorrrrrrrrrrrrrry this the power vector x<-c(0.000, 0.028, 0.668 ,0.999, 1.000)

Comment: @ZB: The purpose of data presentation is not to provide a smooth and lovely shape but to visualize the data as exactly and correctly as possible. When I review a paper and a curve is smoothed without any reason (which has happened), I demand the curve and its relevance to be described in the methods section or removed altogether. That's why I recommended fitting a curve. This may actually have some value to the interpretation. Smoothing does not.

Comment: @MartinWettstein  can you please help me      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601294/i-want-to-plot-the-size-of-a-test-for-example-t-test-vs-the-sample-size-how

Answer (score 5):

Up front, as @MartinWettstein cautions, be careful in when you smooth data and what you do with it (infer from it). Having said that, a simple exponential moving average might look like this.

```r
# replacement data
x <- seq(0, 2, len=5)
y <- c(0, 0.02, 0.65, 1, 1)

# smoothed
ysm <- 
  zoo::rollapply(c(NA, y, NA), 3,
                 function(a) Hmisc::wtd.mean(a, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE),
                 partial = FALSE)

# plot
plot(x, y, type = "b", pch = 16)
lines(x, ysm, col = "red")
```

[image: line plot with smoothed line]

Notes:

- the `zoo::` package provides a rolling window (3-wide here), calling the function once for indices 1-3, then again for indices 2-4, then 3-5, 4-6, etc.
- with rolling-window operations, realize that they can be center-aligned (default of `zoo::rollapply`) or left/right aligned. There are some good explanations here: [How to calculate 7-day moving average in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61777516/3358272))
- I surround the `y` data with `NA`s so that I can mimic a `partial` window. Normally with rolling-window ops, if `k=3`, then the resulting vector is `length(y) - (k-1)` long. I'm inferring that you want to include data on the ends, so the first smoothed data point would be effectively `(0.5*0 + 0.25*0.02)/0.75`, the second smoothed data point `(0.25*0 + 0.5*0.02 + 0.25*0.65)/1`, and the last smoothed data point `(0.25*1 + 0.5*1)/0.75`. That is, omitting the `0.25` times a missing data point. That's a guess and can easily be adjusted based on your real needs.
- I'm using `Hmisc::wtd.mean`, though it is trivial to write this weighted-mean function yourself.

This is suggestive only, and not meant to be authoritative. Just to help you begin exploring your smoothing processes.

Comment: not that there's anything wrong with `zoo::rollapply()` (it's a generally useful tool), but couldn't you also do this particular case with `stats::filter()`?

Comment: @BenBolker, I'm not a pro at `stats::filter`, but it looks like it's right-aligned, whereas looking at the OP's weights, it looks like they need center-aligned. Again, though, I don't know `stats::filter` well, so ... "rolling" to me pushed me quickly to `zoo::roll*`.

Comment: @r2evans is Hmisc a package which must loaded?

Comment: `Hmisc` is a package. It does need to be *installed* but not *loaded* to be able to use `Hmisc::wtd.mean`. But as I said in the answer, it is trivial to come up with a function that can replace it. Perhaps: `my_wtd_mean <- function(vec, wts = 1, na.rm=FALSE) sum(vec*wts, na.rm=na.rm)/sum(wts, na.rm=na.rm)`

Comment: @r2evans may i give the link of te paper so you see the curve ??

Comment: You can [edit] your question and post the link if you want, but I'm not likely to read it (for time), and you may find others prefer to not click on external links. If you *must* show the professor's plot in order to explain why smoothing the curve as done here is wrong, then take a screenshot from the pdf and include that as an image in your question. (You may not have sufficient reputation to show it by default, but we can edit it and show it once you do that.)

Comment: @revans  the curves look better .The question now i think he has used the "ma"  fucntion from the zoo package but i do not know how to define the w vector to use this fucntion

Comment: There is no `zoo::ma`. See its [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html), and if you open [zoo.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf) you'll see the list of documented functions. Further, if you start typing `zoo::ma` on your console and hit tab, RStudio will show you the functions that match that ... and the one that I see is `zoo::make.par.list`, not related to smoothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220455/discussion-between-r2evans-and-z-b).