# I want to plot the size of a test (for example t test ) vs the sample size .How to do it in R?

Tags: r, testing, simulation

i have `x<-rnorm (a,0,1)` and `y <- rnorm( a,0,1)` the a represent the sapmle size I will use different sample size for example (20,30,40,50) and then calculate the size of the test (t test or whatever other test) and then plot it vs sample size.

`plot (a,size of the test)`

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an excercise I do with students to show them the impact of degrees of freedom on critical T-values.

First off, I would not do it once for each sample size but at least 100-1000 times. Then, store all the results and draw density plots to visualize the T-Values. Perhaps also include barplots to show that 5% get significant, independent of the sample size because R corrects for degrees of freedom:

```
ssizes = c(5,10,20,30,50,100,200)
cols = rainbow(7)
t.list = list()
p.list = list()
n = 1000
for(s in ssizes){
  t = c()
  sig = 0
  for(i in 1:n){
    x = rnorm(s,0,1)
    y = rnorm(s,0,1)
    test = t.test(x,y)
    t[i] = test$statistic ## Store the t-value
    if(test$p.value<0.05){sig=sig+1}
  }
  t.list[[as.character(s)]]=t
  p.list[[as.character(s)]]=sig
}

plot(0,0,pch="",main="Density Plots",xlim=c(-4,4),ylim=c(0,0.5),
     xlab="T-Value")
for(i in 1:length(ssizes)){
  lines(density(t.list[[i]]),col=cols[i])
}
legend("topleft",as.character(ssizes),lwd=1,col=cols)

barplot(unlist(p.list),main=paste("Number of tests with p<.05 out of ",n,"tests"),
        xlab="Sample Size")
```

Comment: i am very grateful but still not understand because  it is a little bit different .can you please takle a look at page 8 and 12 from this link they are talking about significance exactley like you but also about oversized tests .....https://eldorado.tu-dortmund.de/bitstream/2003/27803/1/DP_1911_SFB823_Fried_Dehling.pdf

Comment: Ah, yes. They use the power as dependent variable and not the probability distribution of T-Values. And the independent isn't the sample size. But you can replicate this in a for-loop as well.

Comment: my problem is how to get the size of test in R which function must be used? what is the relation between the size of a test and  the rejection rate?

Comment: they used size of a test not the power please see Fig3 page 12 in the pdf not page number 12 in the browser

Comment: I honestly do not get what these authors are calling 'asymptotic size'. That is, what they are doing to the power function to compute this value. And I don't understand why they use three different concepts named 'size' without explaining them. As a reviewer, I would demand clarification before this can be published.