# How to add a value from a row to the previous one in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a dataset similar to the dataset below,

```
Row Date       Value
1   2022-01-03 400
2   2022-01-04 350
3   2022-01-05 368
4   2022-01-06 418
...
```

I would like to calculate `B` by using a formula like below

```r
B = ((Value2 + Value1) / 2) + ((Value3 + Value2) / 2) + ((Value4 + Value3) / 2) + ...
```

I am expecting the output to be

```r
B = ((350 + 400)/2) + ((368 + 350)/2) + ((418 + 368)/2) = 1127
```

**UPDATE**
Also, I would like to have following output based on the formula for calculating `B`,

```
Row Date       Value CUM
1   2022-01-03 400   NA
2   2022-01-04 350   375
3   2022-01-05 368   359
4   2022-01-06 418   393
...
```

I would appreciate if you could help me with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a 'moving average', which will be covered by this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average . E.g.: `rollavg <- c(stats::filter(df$Value, c(0.5,0.5), sides=1)); rollavg; sum(rollavg, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
df |> mutate(B = (Value + lag(Value))/2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark! Would you able please to check the updated question?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sapply` to iterate through the number of rows (minus one) of your dataset.

```r
df <- structure(list(Row = 1:4, Date = c("2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", 
"2022-01-05", "2022-01-06"), Value = c(400L, 350L, 368L, 418L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

B <- sum(sapply(seq_len(nrow(df) - 1), \(x) (df[x + 1, 3] + df[x, 3])/2))
B
[1] 1127
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple arithmetic solution:

```
  sum(
    df$Value[-1],
    df$Value[-length(df$Value)]
  ) / 2

[1] 1127
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr::reframe()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% reframe(B = sum((Value + lag(Value)) / 2, na.rm = TRUE))

#     B
#1 1127
```

Per your edit, where you want both the sum and the individual values:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% reframe(individual = (Value + lag(Value)) / 2,
               B = sum((Value + lag(Value)) / 2, na.rm = TRUE))

  individual    B
1         NA 1127
2        375 1127
3        359 1127
4        393 1127
```