# How to smoothen lines of a line plot without y aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to make the lines of this plot smoother? I would like stay in this `geom_line` + `count` method, so I'm looking for a solution that is based on this code as much as possible.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, group = var1, color = var1)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count", size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "#99b1c9", "B" = "#ff7933", "C" = "#9a6aba")) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "",
       y = "count") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'black', face = 'plain', angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = NULL))
```

Example data

```
set.seed(42)

# Generate example data
years <- seq(2003, 2021, 1)
types <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 730000, replace = TRUE)

# Create DataFrame
df <- data.frame(
  year = sample(years, 730000, replace = TRUE),
  Type = types
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We don't have your data (by inference, it has hundreds of thousands of rows, so it's not easy to include it in your question). However, we can make a reasonable replica of it (see footnote).

Our plot with the data below looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, group = var1, color = var1)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count", linewidth = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(A = "#99b1c9", B = "#ff7933", C = "#9a6aba")) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'black', angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

To make it smooth but retain accuracy of all the points, we can use cubic splines. The easiest way to do this is probably just to count the entries in your data frame instead of getting `stat = "count"` to do it, then make the splines yourself:

```r
df %>%
  count(Year, var1) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(as.character(Year))) %>%
  reframe(count = spline(Year, n, n = 200)$y, 
          Year  = spline(Year, n, n = 200)$x, .by = var1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = count, color = var1)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(A = "#99b1c9", B = "#ff7933", C = "#9a6aba")) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = 2003:2021) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'black', angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Data used - approximation inferred from image in question**

```r
df <- data.frame(Year = factor(c(rep(2003:2021, 
                                     times = c(29000, 28500, 30000, 31000, 
                                                   31500, 30800, 21000, 21500,
                                                   21000, 19500, 18750, 17500, 
                                                   16500, 15800, 16500, 16250,
                                                   16000, 14000, 14250)),
                          rep(2003:2021, times = c(16000, 15800, 19500, 19600,
                                                   20200, 20000, 15250, 16500,
                                                   15750, 15250, 15500, 14900,
                                                   15100, 16000, 17000, 17500, 
                                                   17000, 15250, 15000)),
                          rep(2003:2021, times = c(500, 500, 600, 650, 700,
                                                   750, 750, 700, 700, 690,
                                                   700, 725, 750, 750, 725,
                                                   700, 675, 650, 650)))),
                 var1 = c(rep("B", 409350), rep("C", 317100), rep("A", 12865)))
```

Comment: That looks some pretty spot-on data-inferring!

Answer (score 1):

Smoothing can refers to different things, e.g. a moving average or cubic splines.

For the moving average, there's a nice [smoothing function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862334/6574038) around. `n=3` (the default) calculates a moving average of a three years window, we may set it differently to control smoothing. The data is getting shorter on both ends, depending on the `n`-value, if we set `sides=1` in the function, this only happens on the left side (not shown).

For cubic splines we have `smooth.spline`, which allows to set lots of parameters, I only used the smoothing parameter `spar`.

The first method uses the real data but reduces the information, while the second method is an estimate.

```
> tb <- with(df, table(Type, year)) |> t()
> lb <- rownames(tb)
> 
> par(mfrow=c(1, 3), mar=c(5, 4, 2, 2)+.1)
> matplot(tb, type='l', xlab='year', ylab='count', xaxt='n', ylim=range(tb))
> axis(1, at=seq_along(lb), labels=lb); legend('topright', leg='none', bty='n')
> smooth <- \(x, n=3) as.numeric(stats::filter(x, rep(1/n, n), sides=2))
> apply(tb, 2, smooth, n=3) |>
+   matplot(type='l', xlab='year', ylab='count', xaxt='n', ylim=range(tb))
> axis(1, at=seq_along(lb), labels=lb); legend('topright', leg='MA n=3', bty='n')
> Map(smooth.spline, x=asplit(tb, 2), spar=c(.5, .4, .6)) |> sapply(`[[`, 'y') |> 
+   matplot(type='l', xlab='year', ylab='count', xaxt='n', ylim=range(tb))
> axis(1, at=seq_along(lb), labels=lb); legend('topright', leg='splines', bty='n')
```

### [image]

*Data:*

```
> set.seed(42)
> years <- seq(2003, 2021, 1)
> types <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 730000, replace=TRUE)
> df <- data.frame(
+   year=sample(years, 730000, replace=TRUE),
+   Type=types
+ )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't get it, but when I apply these answers into my data, neither of them produce a smooth plot like seen in the answers

Comment: @Espejito Then you should provide a suitable example for your data, as we usually do on Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: My data has over 700 000 rows. I don't think it is a good example if I take a little sample of it

Comment: @Espejito If you read the link to the end, it says that you can also simulate data, like *AllanCameron* did with a few lines of code; customize it so that it applies to your data, try harder, cheers!

Comment: As an edit I added code for example data. I hope it helps!

Comment: @Espejito Appreciate your data. Please see edits to my answer.